# Convert a 3D array to 2D

Tags: arrays, numpy, resize

I got a numpy array with shape (1,3,300), I wanted to get rid of the first axis and get just the 3*300 2D array.  How can I do it ?

I saw couple of questions like this [numpy with python: convert 3d array to 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838802/numpy-with-python-convert-3d-array-to-2d)
where the requirements are more complex.  Mine seems pretty simple.  Any eacy way to do it ?

Comment: Simply `reshape`? To get 2D, `input_array[0]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy remove a dimension from np array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152031/numpy-remove-a-dimension-from-np-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.squeeze` ?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(3*300).reshape(3,300)

In [3]: a.shape
Out[3]: (3, 300)

In [4]: a = a[np.newaxis, ...]

In [5]: a.shape
Out[5]: (1, 3, 300)

In [6]: b = np.squeeze(a, axis=0)

In [7]: b.shape
Out[7]: (3, 300)
```