# Resize 3D array to 2D

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code that looks like this

```
    number_of_pairs = int(len(path_list) / 2)
    pairs_of_images = [np.zeros(
        (number_of_pairs, self.image_height, self.image_height, 1)) for i in range(2)]
    labels = np.zeros((number_of_pairs, 1))
    size = 105,105
    for pair in range(number_of_pairs):
        image = Image.open(path_list[pair * 2])
        image = image.resize((105,105))
        image = np.asarray(image).astype(np.float64)
        print("before resize is{}".format(image))

        pairs_of_images[0][pair, :, :, 0] = image
```

However, I'm getting an error where

> pairs_of_images[1][pair, :, :, 0] = image
>   ValueError: could not
>    broadcast input array from shape (105,105,4) into shape (105,105)

Is there a way to get rid of the 3rd dimension of the array?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into exactly what you're getting back from np.asarray(). You're leaving it to infer the datatype from what you passed in, do you know what it's actually doing with that and can you rely on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy remove a dimension from np array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152031/numpy-remove-a-dimension-from-np-array)

Comment: That 3d dimension might encode color.  If so, without it you'll just have a b/w image.

Comment: looks like pairs is setup to take single channel images, but you are loading 3 channel ones.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
image = Image.open(path_list[pair * 2])
```

with

```
image = Image.open(path_list[pair * 2]).convert('L')
```

'L' mode turns an image into a single-channel image.