# How to convert 3D array to 2D in python?

Tags: python, 3d, 2d

I have a folder of 2890 tiff lzw compression images as labels for use in deep learning( I have 2 classes, 1 and 2). I want to prepare them as an input of the model that needs a 2D array. so I use `imread()` of `skimage.io` library to read them as a list of 2890 numpy arrays(Y), then convert the list into nd.array (Y_train). now I have Y_train by 3 dimensions (2890, 224, 224) that 224 ,224 are input images size.
Now I need to convert this 3D array to 2D array as (2890,2) that 2 shows the class number.

1. I used `Y_train.reshape(2890,2)` and got this error : `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 145008640 into shape (2890,2).`
2. also I used `to_categorical` from `keras.utils` and got 4D arry as (2890, 224, 224, 3).

How can I convert 3D array (2890, 224, 224) to 2D array (2890,2)?

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate but there's already an answer on here for what you're trying to do [by slicing the numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37152121/9005776)

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a very wrong idea about the reshape operation. The reshape operation makes sure the number of elements in a matrix/vector will be the same no matter what.

So, you can only reshape a matrix of shape  `(A, B, C, D)` to `(A, E)` ***iff*** `B x C x D = E`.

You have completely two different arrays, X with shape (-1, 224, 224) and Y with shape (-1, 2). You can't just reshape them, you have to read the images as numpy array and for each image, append the label to another numpy array, after which you can apply **to_categorical** (Keras) or **LabelEncoder** (scikit-learn).

Follow some online resources to get an idea about reading labels: [Tensorflow read images with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340489/tensorflow-read-images-with-labels)

Comment: It is the code I use : `labels_path = "D:/01_thesis/data/qgis/01_classification/LABEL/"`
`labels = glob.glob(labels_path + "*.tif") `
`labels.sort()`
 
`Y = []`
`for mask in labels:
    label = imread(mask)
    Y.append(label) `  
    
   
`Y_train = np.asarray(Y)`
`Y_train_categorical = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train)`

Comment: This seems okay, even though hard to read the code this way. Is it working?

Comment: it is working but finally I have a array with 4D that is (2890, 224, 224, 3).

Comment: This is the right dimension. 2890 is the number of images you have or samples. 224 = image width, 224 = image height, 3 = image channel (red, green, blue)

Comment: I got this error : `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected fc1000 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2312, 224, 224, 3)` that 2312 is the result of split 2890 into train and test.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you mean to reshape it to a (2890, 224*224), you can do this by putting a -1 in the dimension you want to replace the old dimensions. e.g.
`np.reshape(2890, -1)`