# convert numpy array of lists to array of int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of single element lists:

```
aaa = np.array(
[[ [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0] ],
 [ [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0] ],
 [ [0], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4] ] ]
)
```

How can I turn the inner list into an int so I would have:

```
nnnn = np.array(
    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
     [0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ]]
)
```

It sounds simple but anything I have tried I still end up with a list.

I tried `sum()` as a technique for summing the values in a list, but only ended up summing the whole lot.

Comment: I think the simplest solution is in the second dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152031/numpy-remove-a-dimension-from-np-array - `aaa[:,:,0]`

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
nnnn = np.array([l.flatten() for l in aaa])
```

You can also use [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

```
nnnn = aaa.reshape(-1, aaa.shape[1])
```

Or even simpler:

```
nnnn = aaa[:,:,0]
```

It is useful to note that the last solution returns a view, not a copy. Meaning that changes you apply to the new array will also be reflected in the old array

Comment: Or just `aaa.reshape(arr.shape[:-1])`

Comment: Or even simpler `aaa[:,:,0]`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas everybody.  I dont understand how this is interpreted as a change in dimensions though. I start with a 2D array and want to end with a 2D array. Regardless aaa[:,0] does what I want and gives an array of numbers

Comment: You actually start with a 3D array: `aaa.shape` returns `(3,20,1)`

Comment: You can also mark the answer as accepted for future users and better reference